# Not all invocations running

Tags: c++, glsl, gpgpu, vulkan

I am attempting to implement a simple compute operation of multiplying all values in a buffer by a push constant.

This shader:

```c
#version 450
layout(local_size_x = 1024, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

layout(binding = 0) buffer Buffer { float x[]; };
layout(push_constant) uniform PushConsts { float a; };

void main() {
    x[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] *= a;
}
```

In my current implementation from my prints I get:

```
in:
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
[7]

workgroups: (1,1,1)

out:
7 14 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
```

- `1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1` being the initial values of the buffer.
- `7` being the value of the push constant.
- `(1,1,1)` being the number of workgroups set.
- `7 14 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1` being the resultant values of the buffer after execution.

Strangely only the 1st 2 values have been multiplied by the push constant (which leads me to think only the 1st 2 invocations ran).
I suspect this is likely an issue with memory allocation, although I don’t know where it may be coming from.

I would greatly appreciate any help, and if there is anything I can do to make this post better please let me know.

[Project link](https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/gpu_blas/tree/master/c%2B%2B), [code file link](https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/gpu_blas/blob/master/c%2B%2B/src/main.cpp) and [the .spv files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qnsfZkmN4n_IOtg-2rSnKvgtuKRKNE9x/view?usp=sharing) (`.comp` files are in the repo, but I thought it worth including these in case you didn't want to compile the `.comp` files)

Comment: "_which leads me to think only the 1st 2 invocations ran_" Did you step through your code with a debugger, to confirm this?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I stepped through my code cpu side, but not gpu side, how would I confirm this?

Comment: @onathanWoollett-light "_I stepped through my code cpu side, but not gpu side, how would I confirm this?_" I am not familiar with gpu development. It's just the first, thought, that: "if something doesn't seem to work correctly - don't guess for the reasons - debug to confirm". Don't know if that differs for gpu side development.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I think perhaps you shouldn't comment if you are not familiar with it, it's tricky.

Comment: "_I think perhaps you shouldn't comment if you are not familiar with it, it's tricky._" Perhaps. But seeing majority questions here, where the person asking didn't even bother to use the debugger (or do any kind of debugging) - made be desensitized to all those cases where debugger can't be used, or I not knowing if it can be used. Hence why I wrote my go to comment of "use debugger?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem originated with setting the size of the `VkBuffer` and `VkDescriptorBufferInfo` to the number of values rather than the number of bytes.

Making these changes fixes it:

- `bufferCreateInfo.size = size;` -> `bufferCreateInfo.size = sizeof(float)*size;`
- `bindings[i].range = size;` -> `bindings[i].range = VK_WHOLE_SIZE;`